# Categorical data corrupted when adding to HDFStore

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

Pandas 0.16.2 makes `"11-9553АВП"` category empty string, 0.17 gives `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0`

```
store = pd.HDFStore(r"D:\test10.h5")
store["data"] = pd.Series(("cat", "cat", "11-9553АВП", "hippo")).astype('category')
print(store["data"])
store.close()
```

After debugging i see that pytables `_read_records` truncates 1 byte of some categories. Or maybe they're truncated when written to HDF meta field.

UPD: Okay. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11234 It's fixed with https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/26db1729f2947d95d9a2e51878ba0f297fe24165

Comment: This will be in 0.17.1, coming out next month.

Comment: @Jeff i've patched 0.17 and it works fine. 0.16.2 - doesn't. I'll delete this question after 0.17.1 release

Comment: 0.16.2 won't easily work for this. several fixes went into 0.17.0